# ReWrite Rules in aws load balancer, or in NGINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, redirect

What is the best way to configure ReWrite Rules load balancer, or in NGINX?

I had tried with nginx but encounter with the error everytimes :

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "RewriteEngine On" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:52
```

Rewrites

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myportal.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myportal.com/library/41/lab-bio [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} redesign.myportal.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myportal.com/ [L,R=301]
#deny directory listings,
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule \.svn /not_found [R=403,L]

#Silent Release Localization

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} country=(cn|de|es|kr|it|fr) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(translation/)?(?:cn|de|es|kr|it|fr)/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*[.].{2,4}([?].*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:blog|about/blog|Pav|misc/pavia-consent-form-handler|Shibboleth|lti)/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mvc/control/control.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/$1 [L,R=307]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Pcore-HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]


#SEND GRID REFUSES TO ACKNOWLEDGE, CORRECT DOUBLE ENCODINGS
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?email=.*?)%2540(.*)
RewriteRule ^account/reset /account/reset/?%1\%40%2 [R=301,NE,L]

#RewriteRule ^(cn|de|es|kr)?/?awards/?(.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301,NC]
```

I had tried this :

```
location /country/ {
        #Silent Release Localization

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} country=(cn|de|es|kr|it|fr) [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(translation/)?(?:cn|de|es|kr|it|fr)/? [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*[.].{2,4}([?].*)?$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:blog|about/blog|misc/pavia-consent-form-handler|Shibboleth|lti)/? [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mvc/control/control.php
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/$1 [L,R=307]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Pcore-HTTP [NC]
        RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
        }
```

any short of help would be appriciated.

Comment: AWS Load balancers don't support URL rewriting (at this time) so Nginx is your only option. I would look further into why you are getting that specific error message in Nginx.

Comment: Thanks, Mark for the confirmation, can you also give any suggestions for rewrite errors in Nginx, I have?